# How to check window.location exist or not

Tags: javascript, php, android, jscript-10

My current code is working when location is found. But I want to make a check that if location is not found, it will redirect somewhere else.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        window.location = "theMYApp://"
    }
    else
    {

    }
</script>
```

I want to check if `window.location = "theMYApp://"` does not exist

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check whether *window.location* object is existed on a web browser, you do not check. *window.location* object is always existed.

If you want to check text of 'theMYApp://' in window.location object, you can use below codes.

```
if (window.location.indexOf('theMYApp://') > -1) {
    // theMYApp:// string is found in url
}
```

Comment: I ended up here with the same issue. Ex: I want to know if I can check whether an app is installed in a device before redirecting the website to the app.